# How to find uppercase words in a cell that contains multiple words in Excel?

Tags: excel, filter, uppercase

I am working on a spreadsheet that contains a column with product descriptions. Some of the descriptions contain words that are written in all capital letters but they should not be. Is there any sort of filter I can use to find all the cells with a capitalized word in it? Thanks.

Comment: If all you really want to do is change an all-cap word to a proper-case word, I believe there is a `PROPER` function to make the conversion. So if `A1` is in all caps, if you place `=PROPER(A1)` in cell `B1`, the results should change to proper case.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your text in A1 the following formula in the same row, should tell you whether you have uppercase text:

```
=EXACT(UPPER(A1),A1)
```

Then you can filter the column where your formula is by TRUE

**EDIT**:

Giving a second read at your question I realise that your cell has a full description. I understand it as several words in the same cell. Therefore you would need a user defined function with the following code:

```
Function findUcase(Rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim Txt
    Dim Desc() As String

    Desc = Split(Rng.Value, " ")
    For Each Txt In Desc
        If (UCase(Txt) = Txt) Then
            findUcase = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to eliminate all capital letters? Or keep the first letter of a word capitalized?

You can use Excel's =LOWER(cell) to remove capitalization.
Then if you want to capitalize the first letter, use the =PROPER(cell) function.

There's more about these commands [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-text-to-upper-lower-or-proper-normal-font-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-d9769905-9aed-4964-b2a3-0b895186914f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Hope this helps